# Is there a specific chemical property or concept that explains/predicts the triboelectric series?

Tags: physical-chemistry, materials, electrostatic-energy

Is there a chemical property (perhaps electron affinity?) that can be used to predict where a substance would fall in a triboelectric series such as [this one](https://www.trifield.com/content/tribo-electric-series/)? Or would the cause of the charge imbalance vary on a case by case basis?